# How to sort javascript Array

Tags: javascript

I want to sort array by timestamp, but getting unsorted error

```
var userValue = {
       timestamp,
       username,
       token,
       userid,
       message                      
   };
userArray.push(userValue);
```

this is the array i am getting

[image]

```
userArray.sort(function(a, b) {
return a[0]['timestamp'] - b[0]['timestamp'];
});
```

i want sorted array on timestamp basis

Comment: Unless i'm missing something you have? Do you want ascending or descending?

Comment: can you add the array itself to your question?

Comment: i want descending order

Comment: Why are you doing `userArray[childDatamsg.timestamp]`? Your array has a  length of 1.5 billion now. Use `userArray.push(userValue)`

Comment: i have updated the code using userArray.push(userValue) but getting 2 result??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code sorts by the numerical value of timestamps. It ignores skips over array entries and performs string-to-number conversion of timestamps, if necessary. It assumes that besides 'string' and 'number', timstamps are of no other data type.

```
userArray.filter ( px_item => {
    return (px_item !== undefined);
})
.map ( px_item => {
    if (typeof px_item === "string") {
        return parseInt(px_item);
    } else {
        return px_item;
    }
})
.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (typeof a === "undefined") {
        return -1;
    } else {
        if (typeof b === "undefined") {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return Math.sign ( a['timestamp'] - b['timestamp'] );
        }
    }
});
```

The original code had the sort function wrong. This function is actually a comparison function to determine the relative order of two elements (which in the given use case would be array entries). The order is expressed as one of the numerical values `-1` (`a < b`), `0` (`a = b`), and `1` ( `a > b` ) (in fact, for the result of the comparison to be processed correctly, it suffices that the result has the proper sign, so `Math.sign` could be eliminated).

Comment: @coder_B: It works with `[,,,{ timestamp: "4"},,, {timestamp: 1}]` from the console which is constructed as a trimmed-down analogue of your original data. If you can share your data, I'll be happy to check out the issue.

Comment: @coder_B for starters, in which way does it not work? Does it throw an error?

Comment: i made it work, array was not working outside the firebase code so i place the code inside the firebase code so it gave me correct result

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
userArray[childDatamsg.timestamp] = userValue;
```

adds an object at `timestamp` index. This is why you have an array with the `length` of `1563533788`! Instead `push` the `userValue` object to the `userArray`

```
userArray.push(userValue);
```

Now, it will have indices from `0`.

Then you can sort the array like this:

```
userArray.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp)
```